# Proving non-repitition of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have heard that the sequence $$x_{n+1}=rx_n(1-x_n)$$ for $r$ between $3$ and $4$ does not recur i.e. there is no $a>0$ such that $x_{n+a} = x_n$ and $x_0$ is any number between 0 and 1 exclusive.

I have tried it by brute force up to $x_{120}$ and it does not seem to recur, but is it possible that the 'apparent' non-repetition was due to round-off errors and that it actually recurs?

How would I be able to prove its recurrence/non-recurrence?

Comment: " I have tried it by brute force upto $x_{120}$ and it does not seem to recur" : You really have time to loose with unnecessary things...

Comment: What can $x_0$ be?  Obviously if $x_0=0$ or $x_0=1$ it does recur.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Behavior_dependent_on_r for cycles for r between 3 and 4.

Comment: Clearly there are non trivial fixed points as well.  For any $r$ we solve $x=rx-rx^2$ to get $x=0,\frac {r-1}r$.  If, say, $r=3.5$, then $x=\frac 57$ is a fixed point.

Comment: Oops! $x_0$ is between 0 and 1 exclusive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simply not true.

Indeed for $r=4$, the graph of $f^n=\underbrace{f\circ f\circ \cdots\circ f}_{n\text{ times}}$ is composed of $2^{n-1}$ arches with $y$-coordinates $0\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 0$.

Therefore the graph of $y=f^n$ and $y=x$ has $2^n$ intersections and so $2^n$ period-$n$ points.

In fact the periodic points of that map are dense in $[0,1]$ for $r=4$.